# Catch submit on two different forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html forms with unique ids, `aForm` and `bForm`.

I now want to catch the different submits and handle them differently, but the second form never gets caught on submit. Why?

```
$("form#aForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("A");
});

$("form#bForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("B");
});
```

Entire code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wU4C/7/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
<form id="bForm">
```

instead of:

```
<form id="#bForm">
```

in your HTML markup.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wU4C/8/)**

Also, because `id` is unique, you just need to use `$("#aForm")` and `$("#bForm")`

Comment: is there any difference in `$("form#aForm")` and `$('#aForm')`?

Comment: No difference but it's unnecessary.